# How to do Geograhical AB testing with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to serve certain pages only in one geographical area and have Analytics compare the performance of those pages with the normal pages. Is this something I can do with Analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it for a (extremely huge) fee with Google Analytics 360 and Google Optimize 360, which would allow you to define a GA segment as target audience for the Optimize test.

With standard GA, no. There is no backchannel that would allow you to target, in realtime, users in an A/B test based on Google Data. You would somehow need to do the geographical split yourself and pass in flags for the A/B test to GA. In your reporting you then might be able to segment properly by geography for the results. That will be a second rate solution, and I'm pretty sure you would be better of with a third-party tool.